# nodejs's http.get by providing URI

Tags: node.js

I've been reading the `http` API but I couldn't find a way to do an `http.get()` by just providing the URI I want to access.

For example, I receive from client a complicated URI, say `http://a.b.c:1234/d/e` and I would like to do a `GET` request to it. The problem is that if I have to set the `options` parameter of the `http.get()` method I'm going to end up in complicated string parsing to parse `host`, `port` and `path`. Moreover, I'm not even sure port will always be provided, for example. Is there a way to do an `http.get()` by just providing the full URI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `url` library to do this.

```
var parse = require('url').parse;
http.get(parse(myurl));
```

will work, because the properties on the parsed url object are the same as the options expected by `http.get`.  This isn't a hack, if you look in the docs it says that the two libraries are designed to complement one another like this.

Comment: Thanks! So to set `method`, `headers` etc. what I have to do is something like `var options = parse(myurl); options.method = 'GET';` for example, right?

Comment: Yeah it's cool. For anyone who needs this: I then had some problem using exactly that `options` variable. My suggestion is to make up a new variable and passing `hostname` as `host` from the `parse(myurl)` result and then `port` and `path`, and of course if you need to add `headers` you need that entry too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`url.parse`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/url.html#url.parse):

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');

function download(uri, cb) {
   http.get(url.parse(uri), cb);
}
```